# How to include conditional in mailer layout for mailer method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am designing a mailer layout in Rails. It's a general layout that different mailers will use. In the middle of the general layout, there's a link I want to include but only if it's `user_mailer.rb` with the method `def account_activation(user)` that is sending email. Is there a way to do this?

In the layout I tried:

```
<% if mailer_name == 'user' && ['account_activation'].include?(action_name) %>
```

but this generated the error:

```
undefined local variable or method 'mailer_name' for #<#<Class:0x007f18d0701f30>:0x00000006109c70>
```

If I change `mailer_name` to `mailer` it no longer generates an error but it doesn't display the link either (even though I'm looking at the preview for the account_activation method.

Comment: I don't think this is the best way of doing it. Can you use a partial with the common elements in the layout?

Comment: Why can't you include that link in the corresponding view file i.e, `account_activation.html.erb` directly?

Comment: It is a link inside a footer. So the footer is part of the general layout and lists several links, one of which I would only like to have included for this specific mailer/method. So I can't just include it in the view file (or I would have to include the entire footer in the view). I could make a partial for this one line, but isn't it possible to directly do this inside the mailer layout? Creating an additional file/partial for it, I find makes it less organized.

Comment: I guess `mailer_name == 'user'` should be `mailer_name == 'user_mailer'`

Comment: I'm afraid that still produces the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your layout, in the footer section put something like this:

```
<div id='footer'>
  copyright | terms | privacy
  <% if content_for?(:footer) %>
    |
    <%= yield :footer %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Then in your specific mailer view do this:

```
<% content_for :footer do %>
  special link
<% end %>
```

I do this to add special notes in the footer of emails that vary from email to email. Works great.